# Having an rsync job complete after closing SSH connection

Tags: rsync, nohup

I am transferring a large amount of files from one computer to another using `rsync`. I am doing this by SSHing into the source computer and executing a command like this:

`sudo rsync ssh --rsync-path="sudo rsync" source_dir user@host.com:dest_dir`.

Even if I add `nohup` before this command, whenever I close out the terminal window from which I SSHed, the connection closes.

How can I have it so that my file transfer still continues when I close my SSH connection?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason why `nohup` is not helping you is because the program works with standard IO files.

**Here is' an excerpt from [Wiki Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup#Overcoming_hanging) for nohup:**

> Note - Nohupping
> backgrounded jobs is typically used to avoid terminating them when
> logging off from a remote SSH session. A different issue that often
> arises in this situation is that ssh is refusing to log off ("hangs"),
> since it refuses to lose any data from/to the background job(s).
> This problem can also be overcome by redirecting all three I/O
> streams:
>
> `nohup ./myprogram > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null &` Also note that a
> closing SSH session does not always send a HUP signal to depending
> processes. Among others, this depends on whether a pseudo-terminal was
> allocated or not.

You can use `screen` for that.

Create a screen session with: `screen -S rsync`
then, you detach your screen with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>

And you can disconnect from **SSH**

Comment: I want to add that when performing any work which will if interrupted, eg by a lost connection be problematic, then run it in a screen session.  Screen is designed to protect against accidental connection loss.  You can log in remotely, start screen, start your work, and if you lose connection you can re-connect to any running screen instance.  Screen has got other useful functionality - capturing the session to a log file, having multiple "screens" in a single session (saving network overhead), and multiple viewers (Classroom style).  Also worth mentioning that tmux is a screen alternative.

Comment: FYI, `-S` lets you give a name (in this case "rsync") to your `screen` session.

Answer (score 8):

That screen command is fine, but didn't work for my needs exactly.

This worked a lot better:

```
nohup rsync -va --delete ###.###.###.###:/var/www/sites/ /var/www/sites < /dev/null &
```

Comment: worked for me, just like the accepted answer, thanks